# В хроме не отрабатывает медиа-запрос, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: css

Подскажите, на сайте https://happy-psychology.ru/ идет борьба с адаптацией попапа с формой обратной связи, который на ноутбуках не влезает на страницу.Соорудили медиа-запрос. В опере нормально отрабатывает и все выводится корректно, а вот в хроме никак, он просто не видит этот медиазапрос.Вьюпорт прописан и все вроде бы норм.Пробовали переписать медиа-запрос по разному и ставить его и в начало и в конец, результат тот же - опера видит и обрабатывает, а хром нет.
Пример кода не привожу, так как лучше смотреть на конкретном сайте.
Спасибо за идеи с решением заранее.
Всем здоровья

Comment: SVG анимация отличная. Только одну проблему увидел c "SameSite", на Chrome 81.0.

Comment: Верстку делал я. Супруге сайт писал, потом его забросили.теперь решила ввиду карантина заняться им.-)
Анимация была на всех блоках где есть шары, но от этого страдала отрисовка и иногда подтормаживал сайт на слабых компьютерах..

Comment: Решение то никто не подскажет?В чем может быть такой глюк с медиа?Просто наверное все уже испробовал.
И Максим, а что за проблему то увидел?Ту которую я описывал?

Comment: @MaximLensky понял, учту.Спасибо за совет.
Нет мыслей по решению проблемы?

Comment: @Максим А при чем тут SameSite ? В каком контексте вы это употребляете?
У вас нет мыслей по решению данной проблему?

Comment: @MaximLensky Да, натянуто на wordpress

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107144/discussion-between-deniskins-and-maximlensky).